# How to apply the SQL 'in' keyword in Entity Framework method syntax?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

How to apply the SQL `in` keyword in Entity Framework method syntax?

For example, if I want to write the query in Entity Framework

```
select roleName from Roles where rold_id in (select role_id from UserRoles where user_id = 1);
```

So, how to apply that in Entity Framework method syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner query would be done separately:

```
var inner = UserRoles.Where(r => r.user_id == 1)
                     .Select(r => r.role_id);
```

And then the outer would use the `.Contains` method of the inner.

```
var roleNames = Roles.Where(r => inner.Contains(r.role_id))
                     .Select(r => r.roleName);
```

You could merge it all into a single query, but this is the sanest way to do it. Entity Framework uses deferred queries so it will still do this efficiently.

Edit: Just for completeness sakes, here's a one-line version:

```
var roleNames = Roles.Where(r => UserRoles
                         .Where(ur => ur.user_id == 1)
                         .Select(ur => ur.role_id)
                     .Contains(r.role_id))
                     .Select(r => r.roleName);
```

In a nut shell, instead of it being 'B is in set A', it's more like 'Set A contains B'.